# A convex analysis theorem improvement

Tags: convex-polytopes, convex-analysis

John's theorem states that to any full-dimensional symmetric convex set $K\subseteq R^n$ and any Ellipsoid $E\subseteq R^n$ that is centered at origin, there exists an invertible linear map $T$ so that $E\subseteq T(K)\subseteq\sqrt{n}E$.

Is the $\sqrt{n}$ quantity sharp or could it be improved? Is there special useful scenarios an improvement could be made?

Comment: The cube witnesses that it is sharp. Look at Chapter 12 in the book by Albiac and Kalton, or, for more, consult Nicole Tomczak-Jaegermann's book.

Comment: @BillJohnson Thank you. Any situations we could hope to improve?

Comment: Sure, if the norm generated by the body has good properties such as type.  For example, if the resulting space embeds into $L_p$ isometrically the upper estimate is $n^{|1/p - 1/2|}$ (result of D. R. Lewis).

Comment: @BillJohnson Could you please refer the paper by D.R. Lewis?

Comment: Could you also elaborate to an answer?